# IBM RTC logfile in email notification

Tags: email, build, notifications, rtc, jazz

I am using IBM RTC 4.0.5.
Is there a way to add a logfile to a RTC build email notification?
I do not find any hints in the build definition tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Build Email notification introduced with RTC 3.0+ ([Enhancement #5000](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=50000)) does not include any option to add more information.
As illustrated in [this question](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/105914/rtc-notifications-on-automatic-build), there is no option of additional document.

[image: https://jazz.net/forum/upfiles/rtcNotification.jpg]

Any plan to enhance the Build Email format are... for now not very active:

- [Enhancement 198238: Template-based capability to format emails sent as build notification mails](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=198238)
- [Plan Item 233478: [CCM] Improve Build email notifications](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=233478)-
- [Enhancement 205174: Allow the build email notification to include the list of change sets or work items delivered in that build vs the last build.](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=205174)

The last one has the following comment:

> One option in the short term is to use the `generateChangeLog` Ant task, then send its output using Ant's email task.

Comment: Thank you @VonC for your answer. Since this is not that important I will put the proposed workaround to my backlog.